# Why does my code break for one call to this method, but not another?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurlconnection

I have a Mac application that is supposed to fetch Twitter followers and friends for a given username and then, in turn, ask Twitter for the user NAMES for each of those returned UserIDs. As you can see below, I have a method that will call the Twitter API to get friends/followers (which works fine). It is the userNameForUserID:delegate: method that is causing me problems. I used to do these requests synchronously and return the NSString for the username right then. That (now commented out) line always broke, so I tried doing it with an NSURLConnection asynchronously. Still doesn't work. I don't understand why
[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:...] works for the fetchFollowers... method, but not when I do it the EXACT SAME way in the other...

I put a break point on the line that used to alloc init the NSString with contents of URL, and when I step into it, it doesn't break, return, throw an exception, crash...nothing. It's as if that line just got stepped over (but my application is still blocked.

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

```
NSString * const GET_FOLLOWERS = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=";
NSString * const GET_FRIENDS = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=";
NSString * const GET_USER_INFO = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=";

@implementation TwitterAPI

+ (void)userNameForUserID:(NSNumber *)userID delegate:(id<UserNameDelegate>)delegate
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[GET_USER_INFO stringByAppendingString:[userID stringValue]]];

    //  NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *urlResponse, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [delegate addUserNameToArray:data];
    }];
}

+ (NSArray *)fetchFollowersWithUserName:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[GET_FOLLOWERS stringByAppendingString:userName]];

    NSArray *followerIDs;

    NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    if ([JSON rangeOfString:@"error"].location == NSNotFound)
        followerIDs = [[JSON JSONValue] valueForKey:@"ids"];

    return followerIDs;

}
```

Comment: what kind of exception did it throw?

Comment: Why is one of your `initWithContentsOfURL` using UTF-8 encoding and the other ASCII?

Comment: @fvwmer No exception was thrown or anything...it's like the debugger just gives up on that line.

Comment: @torrey.lyons oops...I originally had them both the same; I changed the one in userNameForUserID to see if it would at least throw an error... No luck! Even sendAsynchronous fails to work though. 

Is there something in the data returned or URL request that would cause the code to just stop responding at that line (initWithContentsOfURL)? Why wouldn't it time out, crash, or error out? I've waited upwards of 10 minutes for any of these things to happen. Still no luck. Thank you all!